# How to extend two activities in same class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar-compat

I'm new to android programming how to extend two activity . In my case I'm using ActionBarActivity
im already extends the  a class for some functionalities how shall i extend two activities my class

any example code will be more useful for me

Comment: just create the new activity in another java file, and add it the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Java class can extend at most 1 other class, so in other words you can't do that.

Comment: you can't..so only interface been used to overcome that.

Comment: You can extends your class only with one Activity. So it is not possible to do that.

Comment: Activity is a class, and Java doesn't support multiple inheritance

Answer (score 1):

This is not much of a Android problem (as Activity is class as any other), it's the way Java works.

Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, so classes can only `extend` one other class.

```
class A extends B{

}
```

Even in this case:

```
class A {

}
```

class A extends another class - `Object` - but it is automatically implied without having to specify it.

If you want to ensure some functionality from several sources you will have to use interfaces and the `implements` keyword:

```
class A extends B implements C,D,E {

}
```